# All the widgets disappear when I try changing DrowdownButton into DropwdownButtonFormField

Tags: flutter

for some mysterious reasons, when I change my `DropdownButton` into a `DropdownButtonFormField`, everything disappear except my background.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppStyle.backgroundColorGreen,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 30),
          child: SizedBox(
            child: (Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                    key: _key,
                    value: selectedOption,
                    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedOption = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                    items: <String>['Roses', 'Tulipes', 'Lys', 'Orchidées']
                        .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        iconSize: 30,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_box_outlined),
            label: "",
            backgroundColor: AppStyle.bottomNavBarColor,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.message_outlined),
            label: "",
            backgroundColor: AppStyle.bottomNavBarColor,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            label: "",
            backgroundColor: AppStyle.bottomNavBarColor,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.map_outlined),
            label: "",
            backgroundColor: AppStyle.bottomNavBarColor,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried setting a GlobalKey because I thought it was required, only that didn't solve my problem. Have you ever experienced this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded, it's a rookie mistake I'm sorry haha. It was enough to set a height and a width for the SizedBox. :D

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppStyle.backgroundColorGreen,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 30),
          child: SizedBox(
            child: (Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                    key: _key,
                    value: selectedOption,
                    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedOption = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                    items: <String>['Roses', 'Tulipes', 'Lys', 'Orchidées']
                        .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        iconSize: 30,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_box_outlined),
            label: "",
            backgroundColor: AppStyle.bottomNavBarColor,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.message_outlined),
            label: "",
            backgroundColor: AppStyle.bottomNavBarColor,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            label: "",
            backgroundColor: AppStyle.bottomNavBarColor,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.map_outlined),
            label: "",
            backgroundColor: AppStyle.bottomNavBarColor,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```